# Can the JVM swap these two lines?

Tags: java

Does JVM understand that these two lines in Method are logically connected and execute them line by line. Or is there a slight possibility that these lines could be swapped and a `NullPointerException` thrown?

This Question is about a single threaded program.

```
   public void foo(Object object) {
      if(object == null) System.out.println("Oops!");
      if(object.list == null) System.out.println("Oops!");
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
public void foo(Object object) {
  if(object == null) return;
  if(object.list == null) System.out.println("Oops!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multithreading or not the *JVM* would never swap those two lines that would be pretty bad to say the least.

That being said your (original) code can throw a `NPE`:

```
if(object == null) System.out.println("Oops!");
if(object.list == null) System.out.println("Oops!");
```

since in the second `if` the object can be null. But I guess you are just using the method to prove a point. Better would have been the following:

```
public void foo(Object object) {
    ....
    else if(object == null) System.out.println("Oops!");
    else if (object.list == null) System.out.println("Oops!");
}
```

---

Your current example:

```
public void foo(Object object) {
   if(object == null) return;
   if(object.list == null) System.out.println("Oops!");
}
```

does not have the same issue.